# NHibernate: Problem trying to save an entity containing collections

Tags: nhibernate, orm, persistence, fluent

I need some help.

I'm just starting out with NHibernate and I'm using Fluent for mappings. Everything seemed to work fine until today.
Here is the story:

I have two tables in my db: **Store** and **WorkDay**
The first table contains info about the store, and the **WorkDay** table contains info about the days of week and start/end time when the store is open.
**Store** contains a Guid **StoreID** PK column that is referenced in the **WorkDay** table.
So I have a mapping file for **Store** where I have a **HasMany** association with the **WorkDay** table, and a corresponding POCO for **Store**.
Now, when I fill in all the necessary data and try to persist it to database, I get an exception telling me that the insert into table **WorkDay** failed because the **StoreID** had null value and the table constraint doesn't allow nulls for that column (which is, of course, expected behavior).

I understand the reason for this exception, but I don't know how to solve it.
The reason why the insert fails is because the **StoreID** gets generated upon insert, but the [b]WorkDay[/b] collection **gets saved first**, in the time when the **StoreID** hasn't yet been generated!

So, how do I force NHibernate to generate this ID to pass it to dependent tables? Or is there another solution for this?

Thank you!

Here's the code for StoreMap

```
public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store> {
    public StoreMap() {
        Id(x => x.StoreID)
            .GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.City);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        Map(x => x.Fax);
        Map(x => x.ImageData).CustomType("BinaryBlob");
        Map(x => x.ImageMimeType);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Phone);
        Map(x => x.Street);
        Map(x => x.Zip);

        HasMany(x => x.WorkDays)
            .Inverse().KeyColumn("StoreID").ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

and this is for the WorkDayMap

```
public class WorkDayMap : ClassMap<WorkDay>{
    public WorkDayMap() {
        Id(x => x.WorkDayID)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.TimeOpen);
        Map(x => x.TimeClose);
        References(x => x.Store).Column("StoreID");
        References(x => x.Day).Column("DayID");
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error if you remove `.Inverse()`?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate shouldn't insert the `WorkDay` first, so there must be an error in your code. Make sure you do all of the following:

1. Add all `WorkDay` objects to the `WorkDays` collection.
2. Set the `Store` property on all `WorkDay` objects to the parent object.
3. Call `session.Save()` for the `Store` but not for the `WorkDay` objects.

edit: You should also note that `ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete()` won't change anything at runtime. This is just an attribute for the hbm2ddl tool. If you want NHibernate to delete removed entries, use `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()`.

Comment: Actually you were right! I was so assured that NHibernate does all the magic with initialization and assignment that I thought calling `store.WorkDays.Add(...)` would be enough, and that the new WorkDay object would automatically take the `StoreID` reference from the calling object! Now I put `store.WorkDays.Add(new WorkDay { Store = store })` and it works exactly how it should.

Answer (score 0):

It probably inserts the Workday before the Store because the first has an `identity` generator. This forces NH to execute an INSERT statement to generate the ID. `guid.comb` is generated in memory, NH doesn't need the database.

NH tries to access the db at the latest possible point in time, to avoid unnecessary updates and to make use of batches. Workday is inserted when you call session.Save, Store is inserted when it flushes the session next time (eg. on commit).

You shouldn't use the identity generator (unless you are forced to use it). It is bad for performance anyway.

---

If it still doesn't work, you probably need to remove the not-null constraint on the foreign key. NH can't resolve it every time. There is some smart algorithm which is also able to cope with recursive references. But there are sometimes cases where it sets a foreign key to null and updates it later even if there would be a solution to avoid it.

Comment: I'd vote you up but I don't have enough reputation! I need the guid, but I'll change the table so that it has a separate ID column and put the guid in another column. I'll see if it works. Thank you!

Comment: I've changed the columns but it didn't help. Removing the NN constraint made inserting possible, but the ID didn't get updated afterwards.

Comment: The guid is **OK**, but the identity isn't good! Use guid.comb or hilo.

Comment: It was guid.comb before. I guess you didn't see that in the code I provided.